# Hetereskedasticity - how to find standard error of the response?

Tags: regression, standard-error

I have data that looks like a classic image below. How do I find the standard error in the predicted response y, where y is from a linear fit? Edit: Standard error perhaps is not the right term. I need to estimate the uncertainty of y (the predicted response).
[image: Data heteroskedasticity]

Comment: Standard error of what? Recall that standard error is a property of the estimator of a parameter, not of a distribution or a data set. Did you mean standard deviation? (The names and ideas are similar, yet they are not the same.)

Comment: residual standard error?

Comment: Do you mean what R calls residual standard error in the summary of an lm?

Answer (score 1):

You can estimate the conditional variance function and use the fitted standard deviations for this. Here is some R code to give you heteroscedastic data:

```
set.seed(12345)
x = runif(1000,1,10)
y = 50*x + 10*x*rnorm(1000)
plot(x,y)
```

The graph is clearly heteroscedastic:
[image]

Now, you can fit a linear regression and a heteroscedastic variance simultaneously via maximum likelihood using the gamlss package in R:

```
library(gamlss)
mod = gamlss(y~x,sigma.fo=~log(x))
summary(mod)
```

The results are as follows:

```
GAMLSS-RS iteration 2: Global Deviance = 10631.88 
GAMLSS-RS iteration 3: Global Deviance = 10631.88 
> summary(mod)
******************************************************************
Family:  c("NO", "Normal") 

Call:  gamlss(formula = y ~ x, sigma.formula = ~log(x)) 

Fitting method: RS() 

------------------------------------------------------------------
Mu link function:  identity
Mu Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -0.9099     1.7690  -0.514    0.607    
x            50.0553     0.5367  93.261   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

------------------------------------------------------------------
Sigma link function:  log
Sigma Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.33427    0.06595   35.39   <2e-16 ***
log(x)       0.98373    0.03906   25.19   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

------------------------------------------------------------------
No. of observations in the fit:  1000 
Degrees of Freedom for the fit:  4
      Residual Deg. of Freedom:  996 
                      at cycle:  3 

Global Deviance:     10631.88 
            AIC:     10639.88 
            SBC:     10659.52 
******************************************************************
```

As you can see, the mean function is estimated well, with $\hat E(Y|X=x) = -0.9099 + 50.0553x$, as compared to the true $E(Y|X=x) = 0 + 50x$.

The model assumes the standard deviation function $\log{\sigma(Y|W = w)} = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 w$; in the code, $W = \log{X}$.  In the simulation, $\sigma(Y|X=x) = 10x$, so  $\log{\sigma(Y|X=x)} = \log{10} +\log{x} = 2.3026 + 1.0 w$. These coefficients are well estimated in the output as $\log{\hat\sigma(Y|X=x)} =  2.33427 + 0.98373 \log{x} $.

You can get the standard deviations for each $X$ value in the data set (and hence for their corresponding $Y$ values) as follows:

```
est.sd.Y = mod$sigma.fv
results = cbind(y,x,est.sd.Y)
head(results)
```

This gives you

```
         y        x est.sd.Y
1 268.0510 7.488135 74.80108
2 224.9855 8.881959 88.47828
3 430.4866 7.848841 78.34428
4 364.5719 8.975121 89.39114
5 425.5612 5.108329 51.34707
6 120.7980 2.497346 25.39643
```

Notice that the estimated standard deviations are approximately $10*X$, the true values.

In practice, the variance function is unknown, and you have to decide on an appropriate function form for the standard deviation function. But this problem is quite similar to the problem of finding the correct form of the mean function.  In both cases, there are various graphs and various fit measures that can help you to decide.